# Typescript - generics in function property does not get resolved

Tags: function, typescript, generics, ecmascript-5, nested-generics

i'm pretty new to typescript and i'm trying to play with nested generics. By now I can't make them work as i would expect, probably i'm missing something obvious. Here is my sample code:

```
type GenericServiceResponse<T> = {
  status: number;
  payload: T;
}

type myServicePayload = {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type myServiceResponse = GenericServiceResponse<myServicePayload>;

class GenericServiceRequest {
  callback?: <T>(data:T) => void;
}

let request = new GenericServiceRequest();

request.callback = <myServiceResponse>(data:myServiceResponse) => {
  console.info(data.payload.name);
};
```

The output of the tsc compiler (target es5) is:

> main.ts(20,23): error TS2339: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'myServiceResponse'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. The main problem were the casts you had in the definition of `callback` and where it is assigned. Besides, the class needs to be generic, too. Otherwise, Typescript does not know what `T` means.

```
type GenericServiceResponse<T> = {
  status: number;
  payload: T;
}

type myServicePayload = {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type myServiceResponse = GenericServiceResponse<myServicePayload>;

class GenericServiceRequest<T> {
  callback?: (data:T) => void;
}

let request = new GenericServiceRequest<myServiceResponse>();

request.callback = data => {
  console.info(data.payload.name);
};
```

As you see, now you don't have to speficy the type of `data` in the las sentence, it`s inferred by the definition of request.